# HOC import TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just tried to use a simple HOC with react.
Here is the function :

```
import React from "react"

const withOptions = (WrappedComponent) => {

  return class extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent { ...this.props } />
    }
  }

}

export default withOptions
```

The problem seems to be in the way i export/import it.

Imported and used in a simple way, it works :

```
import withOptions from "./Options"
...

class BilanClimatique extends React.Component{
  ...
}
const StyledBilanClimatique = withStyles(styles)(BilanClimatique)
export default withOptions(StyledBilanClimatique)
```

But if i use an intermediate file like index.js

```
import withOptions from "./Options"

export {
  withOptions
}
```

And import it in my component like that

```
import {
  withOptions
} from "./index"
```

Here is what i get

[image: HOC error]

Can someone help me understand this ?

**EDIT :**

I found that the component that is using the HOC is imported from the same file as the HOC :

```
import withOptions from "./Options"
import BilanClimatique from "./BilanClimatique"

export {
  withOptions,
  BilanClimatique
}
```

And that causes the problem, but I don't understand why...
Here is a sandbox with the problem https://codesandbox.io/s/r074735yvo

Comment: I can't seem to replicate it. https://codesandbox.io/s/wq7xnmmx5w Could there be something else missing when you trimmed your code for SO?

Comment: I found the problem and kind of replicate the error: the component which is using `withOptions` hoc is also imported from `index` https://codesandbox.io/s/r074735yvo ... But i don't understand why this is a problem...

Comment: Thanks for replicating it. I will dig a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the question, I learnt a lot about modules while digging around. Hope my answer is clear, else let me know and I will try to elaborate further.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with hoisting of 'exports'. From what I can see, the `imports` get [hoisted](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_imports-are-hoisted), but I could not see anything similar for `exports`.

The flow which causes problem ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9829x5241p)):

App.js:

```
import { BilanClimatique } from "./components/index";
```

./components/index.js:

```
// just using the "re-export" shortcut
export { default as BilanClimatique } from "./BilanClimatique";
export { default as withOptions } from "./Options";
```

./components/BilanClimatique.js:

```
import { withOptions } from "./index";
```

./components/Options.js:

```
const withOptions = WrappedComponent => {
  return ... //snipped code

export default withOptions;
```

When App.js asks index.js for BilanClimatique, it in turn asks the *same* index.js for `withOptions`. But since exports don't seem to be hoisted, index.js has not yet made withOptions available.

How to solve:

1. Ordered exports:

in ./components/index.js, change the order of exports as per your dependency:

```
// just using the "re-export" shortcut
export { default as withOptions } from "./Options";
export { default as BilanClimatique } from "./BilanClimatique";
```

I would not recommend it. It is very fragile.

2. Use index.js to only expose to outside your namespace. Inside your namespace, rely on explicit imports.

i.e. in ./components/BilanClimatique.js:

```
import withOptions from "./Options";
```

3. If you have a very large codebase, use multiple index.js for exporting your "contracts". Take a look at the codebases of various library authors, I think that is the strategy they take.

I would personally recommend #2 over #3 unless you run into problems with #2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I will go for the #2 and try to have a look at others strategy. Great answer :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. It was a nice TIL moment for me too!

Comment: This was really helpful, I simply changed the way we import these 'pure' components and the tests now pass!

Comment: after searching for hours this one helped .. it was hoisting and what order did i put  imports

Answer (score 0):

`.` doesn't look as a great import path. Try to import from 'index' file.

```
import {
  Logo,
  withOptions
} from "./index"
```

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN yes, i mean that the component Logo is imported this way and is imported without error