# TypeError: Object(…) is not a function when trying to implement a HOC

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components, high-order-component

I've tried to read [the accepted answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626311/hoc-import-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function) and in other posts, but can't quit figure out if this helps me or not. I feel like the case there is different.

I've looked at a few examples on how to use HOC and it seems just like I do. Is it because I am trying to use HOC to implement `connect`?

This is my HOC:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const withResults = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    results: state.results
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withResults);
```

And this is my component I am trying to wrap with the HOC:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import WithResults from "./withResults";
import SingleResult from "../singleResult/Primary";
import { PrimarySearchTermContext } from "../../providers/PrimarySearchTermProvider";


const PrimaryResults = props => {
  const { currentSearchTerm } = useContext(PrimarySearchTermContext);

  const compare = (a, b) => {
    if (a.resultCount > b.resultCount) return 1;
    if (b.resultCount > a.resultCount) return -1;

    return 0;
  };

  const renderResults = () => {
    //According to requirements, this search starts showing results after the third character
    if (props.results[0] === undefined || currentSearchTerm.length <= 2)
      return null;

    const relevantResults = [];
    props.results[0]
      .sort(compare)
      .reverse()
      .map(result => {
        if (result.term.toLowerCase().includes(currentSearchTerm.toLowerCase()))
          relevantResults.push(result);
      });

    return relevantResults.slice(0, 4).map(result => {
      if (currentSearchTerm === result.term) return null;
      return (
        <SingleResult
          searchTerm={currentSearchTerm}
          term={result.term}
          resultCount={result.resultCount}
          key={result.term}
        />
      );
    });
  };

  return <div className="results">{renderResults()}</div>;
};

export default WithResults(PrimaryResults);
```

The error I keep getting is for the last line of the export in the wrapped component.

Answer (score 0):

try to export like this:

```
const withResultHoc = connect(mapStateToProps)(withResults);
export default withResultHoc;
```

Comment: export default withResults(connect(mapStateToProps)); ?

Comment: If I do that the error changes to `TypeError: Class constructor  cannot be invoked without 'new'`

Comment: Try to use this in your child component:
    `export default withResults(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PrimaryResults));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
`export default compose(withResult, connect(.....))(PrimaryResults)`

Comment: But the primary results are the wrapped component. the whole point of me creating this HOC is for it to take care of the connect function without the PrimaryResults (and other components in the same level) having to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

So exporting like this ended up being the solution to me problem:

```
const composedWithResults = compose(connect(mapStateToProps, null), withResults);

export default composedWithResults;
```

As a beginner I'll be honest and say I don't quit know why, but it works. An explanation form someone who does would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your HOC:

```
 export default (WrappedComponent) => connect(mapStateToProps)(withResults(WrappedComponent));
```